# Wordpress page not updating after make changes

Tags: wordpress, updatepanel

[image]

Wordpress page not updating after making changes, just button got disabling and display updating...

Comment: Do you installed plugins? if yes please uninstall and check with any update. Then you can understand which plugin has the compatibility issue.

Comment: I checked it and it's king composer wordpress plugin issue. can you guide me on how can I solve it?